# Waiting for DialogActivity to return before continuing executing of the main thread

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How would I force the current thread to wait until another has finished before continuing.

In my program the user selects a `MODE` from an `AlertDialog`, I want to halt executing of the program before continuing as the mode holds important configuration for the gameplay.

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setItems(R.array.game_modes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
            case 0:
                setMode(TRAINING_MODE);
            case 1:
                setMode(QUIZ_MODE);
            default:
                setMode(TRAINING_MODE);
                break;
            }

            //continue loading the rest of onCreate();
            contineOnCreate();
        }
    })
    .create().show();
```

If this is impossible can anyone give a possible solution?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? The method contineOnCreate() should only be called if the user clicks something. So what isn't working?

Comment: No it doesn't - the onStart() callback loads before the mode is selected because the Alert loads in it's own thread therefore allowing the main thread to continue loading as normal

Comment: and these things have to be in onStart() can't these calls be move into contineOnCreate()?

Comment: No because some of the onStart() code controls activity state when the Activity loses focus and needs to be re-configured when the activity re-gains focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I force the current thread
>   to wait until another has finished
>   before continuing.

You don't.

> In my program the user selects a MODE
>   from an AlertDialog, I want to halt
>   executing of the program before
>   continuing as the mode holds important
>   configuration for the gameplay.

No, you don't. You want to exit out of the main application thread (so the dialog appears), and then kick off gameplay after the user dismisses the dialog by one means or another.

> because the Alert loads in it's own
>   thread therefore allowing the main
>   thread to continue loading as normal

No, it doesn't. All UI is done on the main application thread, dialogs included.

> No because some of the onStart() code
>   controls activity state when the
>   Activity loses focus and needs to be
>   re-configured when the activity
>   re-gains focus.

Then don't do any of that until after the user has dismissed the dialog by one means or another.

Another option: move your "dialog" UI options into its own activity, and have users pass through it en route to the game activity.

Comment: ok, looks like I will have to re-think my approach.  I might use the extras bundle to pass the mode and display the mode from the main screen.

Comment: That should work. A dialog should be considered an extension of an activity's basic UI, to handle things that might take up too much screen space otherwise (e.g., using a `DatePickerDialog` rather than a `DatePicker`). A dialog should not be considered a key flow of navigation (e.g., have to do something in a dialog before work can proceed).